# Using an async .NET method as a Win32 API callback

Tags: .net, multithreading, winapi, callback, marshalling

I am using Win32 API inside a .NET Core application. I call Win32 API function with a callback parameter:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public delegate void CALLBACK(StructType data);


[DllImport("somewindows.dll", SetLastError = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern HRESULT RegisterWin32Callback(CALLBACK CallbackAsync);


private async void CallbackAsync(StructType data)
{
    await MyFuncAsync();
}

RegisterWin32Callback(CallbackAsync);
```

I need to call async .NET methods from a callback, so I am trying to make a callback to be async too.

The parameter in the Win32 API callback is defined as:

```
IN StructType data
```

However, as soon as in, out and ref are not supported in .NET async methods, I removed "in" form .NET declaration. My understanding that IN does not play any role in terms of marshaling.

Are there any potential issues with such an approach?

Comment: Did you try to do that? Which issues are you faced with?

Comment: It is working perfectly, including try-catch. But: 1. "async void" is not recommended as far as I understand. 2. 'StructType data' was originally 'IN StructType data' in C++ header file. I removed "in" because it is not supported with async method. I guess these may cause issues finally.

Comment: There is no machinery built into the Windows API that would magically turn C-style callbacks into asynchronous function calls. That's something you would have to layer on top of the API. Doing this implies that you are now responsible for managing object lifetimes. Again, there's no machinery built into the Windows API that provides the *"if an object is reachable in code, it will be alive"* guarantee. That leaves you with 2 options: Either synchronously waiting on your .NET call from the callback, or diving head first into developing your own asynchronous implementation.